# Spring Data Mongo DB Repository FindBy not working

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data

I'm trying to add a custom query to a MongoRepository instance, but it's not working. Section 10.3 in [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.repositories) describes what I'm trying to do. I've tried 4 different ways of doing it, but nothing seems to work...

My Code

```
public interface MyRepository extends MongoRepository<StudentEO,CustomId>{

    //1st attempt. 
    //StudentEO findByFirstName(String firstName);

    //2nd attempt. 
    //@Query("{ 'firstName' : ?0 }")
    //StudentEO findByFirstName(String firstName);

    //3rd attempt.
    //List<StudentEO> findByFirstName(String firstName);

    //4th attempt
    @Query("{ 'firstName' : ?0 }")
    List<StudentEO> findByFirstName(String firstName);
}

@Document(collection = "data_point_metadata")
public class StudentEO {

    @Id
    private CustomId id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private StudentType studentType;

    ...

    getters and setters...
}

@Component
public class StringToStudentTypeConverter implements Converter<String, StudentType> {

    @Override 
    public StudentType convert(String source) { 
        if(source == null){
            return null;
        }

        try{
            return StudentType.valueOf(source.trim().toUpperCase());
        }catch(Exception e){
            LOGGER.error("invalid dataType value - "+e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the logs I see:

```
c.f.f.s.w.m.u.StringToDataTypeConverter - invalid studentType value - No enum constant ...StudentType.John
o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - find using query: { "firstName" :  null } fields: null ...
```

and I don't get anything back. When I debug it, my service layers is definitely passing a valid firstName. Not null.

I'm also using a default findAll() repository method, and it works fine.

```
PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(pageNumber, pageSize != 0 ? pageSize : defaultPageSize);
Page<StudentEO> studentsPage = myRepository.findAll(pageRequest);
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using the following version of spring apis:

- spring-core 4.1.7.RELEASE
- spring-data-commons 1.9.3.RELEASE
- spring-data-mongodb 1.6.3.RELEASE

Comment: I just run an example with your code and it worked. I would suggest debugging in `AbstractMongoQuery.execute(Object[] parameters)`. Does it get the parameters?
If the parameter is contained in the Object[], the next two lines could show you something: `MongoParameterAccessor accessor = new MongoParametersParameterAccessor(method, parameters);
  Query query = createQuery(new ConvertingParameterAccessor(operations.getConverter(), accessor));`

Comment: @WornOutSoles I think a String->StudentType converter I added is causing this. It's trying to convert firstName to a StudentType, fails and returns null. Just not quite sure why would it go after the firstName if it's supposed to be a String. I updated my code to show the Converter.

Comment: @WornOutSoles It appears I might not need the String - Enum converters. It seems to happen automatically. Thanks for the AbstractMongoQuery.exectue debugging tip.

Comment: you're welcome, I'm glad it helped!